# Very simple parallax code has performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, parallax, requestanimationframe

For a parallax-effect, I created a simple script in native Javascript, but it seems to fail somewhere I can't see. That's why I already added the `requestAnimationFrame`-functionality, but it doesn't seem to really help.

My relevant code is as follows:

```
var $parallax, vh;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $parallax = $('.parallax');
    vh = $(window).height();

    $parallax.parallaxInit();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    vh = $(window).height();

    $parallax.parallaxInit();
});


$.fn.parallaxInit = function() {
    var _ = this;
    _.find('.parallax-bg')
        .css('height', vh + (vh * .8) );

}



//call function on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(parallax);
});

var parallaxElements = document.getElementsByClassName('parallax'),
    parallaxLength = parallaxElements.length;

var el, scrollTop, elOffset, i;

function parallax(){

    for( i = 0; i < parallaxLength; i++ ) {

        el = parallaxElements[i];
        elOffset = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        // only change if the element is in viewport - save resources
        if( elOffset < vh && elOffset + el.offsetHeight > 0) {

            el.getElementsByClassName('parallax-bg')[0].style.top = -(elOffset * .8) + 'px';

        }

    }

}
```

I think it's weird that [this script by Hendry Sadrak](https://codepen.io/hendrysadrak/pen/ctgaz?editors=1010) runs better than my script (on my phone) while that is not really optimised, as far as I can tell.

Update: I checked if `getBoundingClientRect` might be slower in some freak of Javascript, but it's about 78% faster: https://jsperf.com/parallax-test

Answer (score 4):

So here is the downlow on JS animations on mobile devices. Dont rely on them.

The reason is that mobile devices have a battery and the software is designed to minimize battery load. One of the tricks that manufacturers use (Apple does this on all their mobile devices) is temporarily pause script execution while scrolling. This is particularly noticeable with doing something like parallax. What you are seeing is the code execution - then you scroll, it pauses execution, you stop scrolling and the animation unpauses and catches up. But that is not all. iOS uses realtime prioritization of the UI thread - which means, your scrolling takes priority over all other actions while scrolling - which will amplify this lag.

Use CSS animation whenever possible if you need smooth animation on mobile devices. The impact is seen less on Android as the prioritization is handled differently, but some lag will likely be noticeable.

Red more here: https://plus.google.com/100838276097451809262/posts/VDkV9XaJRGS

Comment: Thanks, well-explained. However, why does this script: https://codepen.io/hendrysadrak/pen/ctgaz?editors=1010 NOT jitter on my screen while its code is way less optimised?

Comment: I wish I could answer that, but that is above my pay grade :). It likely just boils down to the small differences in how the client prioritizes the code. One thing I did notice as a difference between your and his code is that he is using a trigger to call all position changes at the same time on scroll - rather than using separate events.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! I used `transform: translate3d` instead, which works with the GPU instead of the CPU. Which makes it much smoother, even on mobile.

http://codepen.io/AartdenBraber/pen/WpaxZg?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Creating new jQuery objects is pretty expensive, so ideally you want to store them in a variable if they are used more than once by your script. (A new jQuery object is created every time you call `$(window)`).

So adding `var $window = $(window);` at the top of your script and using that instead of calling `$(window)` again should help a lot.

Comment: But how should that be affecting my scroll-event? Those functions are only called at `ready` and `resize`, not on scroll. Sure, they're a bit slower, but shouldn't have anything to do with the parallax-jitters I'm experiencing.

Comment: Ah that's correct. I skimmed the code and thought you had `$(window)` inside of your `scroll` event. In your case, I would recommend setting up the profiler in the dev tools